# intervlan router-on-stick with Nexus

Tags: vlan, cisco-nexus

Ok people, same drill on router-on-stick inter-vlan routing between a Cisco router and Cisco switch. Except this time, it's the expensive Nexus instead of Catalyst.

```
2911#show vlans

Virtual LAN ID:  1 (IEEE 802.1Q Encapsulation)

   vLAN Trunk Interface:   GigabitEthernet0/2

 This is configured as native Vlan for the following interface(s) :
GigabitEthernet0/2

   Protocols Configured:   Address:              Received:        Transmitted:
        Other                                           0                7772

   1431 packets, 403183 bytes input
   7772 packets, 551049 bytes output

Virtual LAN ID:  100 (IEEE 802.1Q Encapsulation)

   vLAN Trunk Interface:   GigabitEthernet0/2.100

   Protocols Configured:   Address:              Received:        Transmitted:
           IP              10.0.0.1                     2                   3
        Other                                           0                  13

   2 packets, 128 bytes input
   16 packets, 1798 bytes output

Virtual LAN ID:  200 (IEEE 802.1Q Encapsulation)

   vLAN Trunk Interface:   GigabitEthernet0/2.200

   Protocols Configured:   Address:              Received:        Transmitted:
           IP              10.1.0.1                     0                   3
        Other                                           0                  28

   0 packets, 0 bytes input
   31 packets, 2488 bytes output
```

This is my 2911 router interface.

```
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 no ip address
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2.100
 encapsulation dot1Q 100
 ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2.200
 encapsulation dot1Q 200
 ip address 10.1.0.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
!
```

This is one of nexus trunk interface and vlan output.

```
interface Ethernet1/48
  switchport mode trunk

interface Vlan100
  no shutdown
  ip address 10.1.0.13/24

interface Vlan200
  no shutdown
  ip address 10.0.0.13/24
```

But 2911 and Nexus still can't ping each other's vlan inter ip.

What am I doing wrong or missing that's necessary in addition to what we usually do on a Catalyst?

Thanks.

[Update: After Ron M's catch]

```
C#          ping 10.0.0.1
PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=254 time=0.804 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=254 time=0.57 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=254 time=0.534 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=254 time=0.536 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=254 time=0.526 ms

--- 10.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0.00% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.526/0.593/0.804 ms
C#          ping 10.1.0.1
PING 10.1.0.1 (10.1.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.1.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=254 time=0.769 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=254 time=0.56 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=254 time=0.534 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=254 time=0.522 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=254 time=0.53 ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VLAN 100 is on different networks in the two devices:

2911 is `10.0.0.0/24`:

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/2.100
 encapsulation dot1Q 100
 ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
!
```

Nexus is `10.1.0.0/24`:

```
interface Vlan100
  no shutdown
  ip address 10.1.0.13/24
```

VLAN 200 is on different networks in the two devices:

2911 is `10.1.0.0/24`:

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/2.200
 encapsulation dot1Q 200
 ip address 10.1.0.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
!
```

Nexus is `10.0.0.0/24`:

```
interface Vlan200
  no shutdown
  ip address 10.0.0.13/24
```

Also, you don't want `ip nat inside` on `interface GigabitEthernet0/2` since it doesn't have an IP address. You only need it on the subinterfaces.

Comment: Thanks and please see update. I can be so stupid, so sometimes I'm glad we have each other to proof-read.